# Pip django app installation

Tags: python, django, pip

I am currently working on an internal ad manager as a django app! It is called "glinks" which basically means graphical link. Kinda makes sense I guess. I wanted to make it available through pip so I went through all the steps and it can now be found here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-glinks/

For some reason when I install it straight from the tar file on the page i get the proper folder/file structure.

```
django-glinks
  *files needed
    glinks
      *files needed
        templatetags
          *files needed
```

BUT! When I used `pip install django-glinks` i dont get the templatetags directory or files with it! so instead i get this:

```
django-glinks
  *files needed
    glinks
      *files needed
```

I am pretty new to this so it would be great if someone could help me out. Here is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import os

README = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.txt')).read()

# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

    setup(
        name='django-glinks',
        version='0.1.4',
        author='Shawn Simon',
        author_email='shawn.simon.developer@gmail.com',
        packages=['glinks'],
        url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-glinks/',
        license='LICENSE.txt',
        description='Interal add manager for django sites.',
        long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
        install_requires=[
            "Django >= 1.6.0",
        ],
        classifiers=[
            'Environment :: Web Environment',
            'Framework :: Django',
            'Intended Audience :: Developers',
            'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License', # example license
            'Operating System :: OS Independent',
            'Programming Language :: Python',
            'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
            'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
            'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
        ],
    )
```

and here is my manafest.in :

```
include *.txt
recursive-include docs *.txt
recursive-include docs *.py
recursive-include docs *.rst
recursive-include docs Makefile
recursive-include pypiuploader *.py
recursive-include tests *.py
include glinks/templatetags/*.py
include *.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Correcting `setup` - completing `packages` var

Good you show the `setup.py`. It is missing the reference to the `glingks.templatetags` package.

If you add this package into `packages` as shown below, it will work. For me, I was after this modification ïmporting not only `glinks`, but also `glinks.templatetags`.

```
setup(
    name='django-glinks',
    version='0.1.4',
    author='Shawn Simon',
    author_email='shawn.simon.developer@gmail.com',
    packages=['glinks', "glinks.templatetags"],
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-glinks/',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Interal add manager for django sites.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "Django >= 1.6.0",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License', # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been going crazy over this for far too long.